# ssh to aws instance encoding issue

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04, gnome-terminal

I'm trying to connect to an EC2 instance on AWS, and I'm getting this as the command prompt:
]133;C;]133;D;130]1337;RemoteHost=ec2-user@master]1337;CurrentDir=/home/ec2-user]133;A[ec2-user@master ~]$ ]133;B

I'm using gnome-terminal on Ubuntu 16.04. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your prompt by changing the variable PS1.
Try to run the line: 
    `PS1='\u@\h:\w\$'`

If you like it you can add this line to your `.bash_profile`.

This will set the prompt to `user@host:cwd$`

The strange "]133;" is the setting of the color in the prompt

For reference the default prompt for raspian is:

```
PS1=\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w \$\[\033[00m\]
```